# Why is my custom slug method skipping it's code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I am trying to perform the following actions to alter my urls:

1. parse instances of "an-" from my url
2. remove a prefix of "the-" from my url if present.

```
class BlogPost < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :custom_slug, use: :history

  ...

  def custom_slug
    a = "#{title.to_s}"

    # goal is to remove the following words from url: an
    # the word being removed goes after "/\b and before \b/"
    # "#{title}".gsub! "/\ban\b/", ""
    a.gsub! "/\ban-\b/", ""

    # this should remove "the-" from the beginning of a slug if it's there
    if a.start_with?("the-")
      a.slice! "the-"
    end

    return a
  end

end
```

A **title** I'm trying to alter is **"the example of an the post"**

`friendly_id` converts to: `/the-example-of-an-the-post`

I want: `/example-of-the-post`

But my code to do this is not being executed and is just returning the original string. I know the `.slice!` portion of my code should work but I don't actually know if my code is correct or effective in this application of it.

---

**Update**

Following advice from @Schwern I came to some other conclusions to fix my issue:

`a = "#{title.to_s}"` to `a = "#{title.to_s.downcase}"`

Replaced faulty REGEX with a simpler solution:

```
if a.include?(" an ")
  a.gsub! " an ", " "
end
```

And directly from Schwern I was targeting something in the `:slug` and not the `:title` so it just had to change to this:

```
if a.start_with?("the ")
  a.slice! "the "
end
```

Comment: Do you have `include FriendlyId` in your ApplicationRecord? Did you try extracting the function and testing it on its own? How do you know the method is not being called?

Comment: What is in `title`? Are you sure it's `the-example-of-an-the-post` and not `The example of an the post`?

Comment: @Schwern I have `extend FriendlyId`. I updated my question to include that.

Comment: Note that you can just write `a = title.downcase`. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Thank you for that! It's much cleaner and I didn't know the `.downcase` method stringified too.

Comment: It doesn't, `title` is (presumably) already a String. You couldn't call downcase on it if it wasn't. If you do need to stringify, use just `.to_s`, no quotes. `"#{var}"` implicitly stringifies, and you should only use it if you're building a new string. `"The title is #{title}"`. Try rubocop and rubocop-rails to audit your code and learn more best practices. Some are pretty arbitrary, but most are useful. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're matching against the title of the post. Presumably the post is not titled `the-example-of-an-the-post`, that is how it would appear after conversion to a URL. The title is likely `The example of an the post`.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips

```rb
# a = "#{title.to_s.downcase}"
# No need for interpolation inside "#{}".
# If the title always returns a string, you don't need to_s.
# Add to_s only if there is a possibility of returning nil.
# It is also good to better name the variable
new_slug = title.downcase

new_slug.gsub!(" an ", " ") if new_slug.include?(" an ")
new_slug.slice!("the ") if new_slug.start_with?("the ")

# Don't need the return statement on the last line
new_slug
```